# How to input several optimized images in one page? (netlify-cms + gatsby-image + gatsby)

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby, netlify-cms

I got a weird result trying to use two different image widgets to input content on a single page: I can get the images paths with graphql, but the images are not processed with gatsby-image, meaning I only get a string containing the path, not the usual object.

Other pages with only one image do not have this problem. That is, using gatsby-remark-images + gatsby-remark-relative-images + gatsby-image

Relevant part of my config.yml:

```
      - label: Impression 2D/3D
        name: impression
        file: src/content/impression.md
        fields:
          - label: Image Impression 3D
            name: image-3d
            widget: image
            allow_multiple: false
          - label: Présentation Impression 3D
            name: impression-3d
            widget: markdown
          - label: Image Impression 2D
            name: image-2d
            widget: image
            allow_multiple: false
          - label: Présentation Impression 2D
            name: impression-2d
            widget: markdown
```

Comment: It'd be immensely helpful if you could provide a live repo that demonstrate this behavior. Thanks!

Comment: Or just the file where the query that is calling on the yaml exist.